# Integrating Keycloak in Micro Frontends with Single SPA and Angular

Tags: javascript, keycloak, micro-frontend, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I'm new to micro frontends and I'm currently building an application using Single SPA, where the child applications are written in Angular 16. I'm now at the stage where I need to integrate Keycloak authentication into my micro frontend architecture.

My question is: should I incorporate Keycloak directly into the Single SPA root configuration, or should I create a separate app just to handle Keycloak authentication?

Comment: Don't know what Keycloak is (maybe you can provide a link), but generally speaking, authentication for the user should only happen once.  If multiple MFE's require the same authentication, my guess would be for the root config to perform it, then pass along security data to the MFE's.